# Regex group match exactly n times

Tags: python, regex, string

I have to validate next string format:

```
text-text-id-text
```

Separator is character '-'. Third column must always be id. I wrote next regex (in python) which validates string:

```
import re

s = 'col1-col2-col3-id' # any additional text at the end
                        # is allowed e.g. -col4-col5
print re.match('^(.*-){3}id(-.*)?$', s) # ok 
print re.match('^(.*-){1}id(-.*)?$', s) # still ok, is should not be
```

I tried adding non-greedy mode, but result is still the same:

```
^(.*?-){1}id(-.*)?$
```

What am I missing in my regex? I could just validate string like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.split('-', 'col1-col2-col3-id')
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'id']
```

And then check if the third element matches id, but I am interested in why does the first regex works as mentioned above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first regex is incorrect because it asserts that `id` is present **after** the first three items.
Your second regex matches the string incorrectly because `.*` matches hyphens as well.

You should use this regex:

```
/^(?:[^-]+-){2}id/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/rB5iV5/5)!

And if you feel a need to anchor a regex to the end, use `/^(?:[^-]*-){2}id.*$/`!

---

As mentioned by [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker), consider asserting `id` at the end of the item:

```
/^(?:[^-]+-){2}id(?![^-])/
```

Here is an [UPDATED regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/rB5iV5/6)!

Comment: +1, and perhaps use a lookahead assertion `(?=-|$)` after `id` to make sure that the third column isn't something like `idiom`.

Comment: Probably, but we don't know which characters are allowed between `-`s, perhaps `id.txt` would be valid and shouldn't be matched.

Comment: @georg any other column can also be id. Valid string is also id-id-id-id. I then further validate rows of column id. I check for whitespaces.

Comment: @Unihedron .* matches hyphens as well. Thnx for this. Is ?: neccessary?

Comment: I understand now about ?:. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Comment: @broadband Excellent! [Check this out, too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @TimPietzcker string 'text-text-id' does not pass when regex /^(?:[^-]+-){2}id(?![^-])/ is used. Therefore I use this: ^(?:[^-]*-){2}id(-[^-]*)?$  [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fX5sE0/2)